# How do I change a counter of the form <h3 id="counter">708</h3>?

Tags: html, tags, counter

I have a site with counters, and has `<h3 id="counter">0</h3>`. How do I change the counter number? Where can I find it to change?

This is the code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 project">
                    <h3 id="counter">0</h3>
                    <h4>Awesome Projects</h4>
                    <p>Dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit quisque tempus eget diam et lorem a laoreet phasellus ut nisi id leo molestie. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 project">
                    <h3 id="counter1">0</h3>
                    <h4>Happy Customers</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit quisque tempus eget diam et. laoreet phasellus ut nisi id leo.  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 project">
                    <h3 id="counter2" style="margin-left: 20px;">0</h3>
                    <h4 style="margin-left: 20px;">Professional Awards</h4>
                    <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit quisque tempus eget diam et laoreet phasellus ut nisi id leo molestie adipiscing vitae a vel. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: FYI - I would also like it to display a counting percentage so before 0% and counts to 61% etc

Answer (score 1):

add the following to the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;

    // adds 1 to count every 1000 milliseconds and updates it for the user
    window.setInterval(function()
    {
        count++;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = count;
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: I am really stupid. Can you please explain exactly how/where?

Comment: I changed it in my answer :)

Comment: Here is a good link that will help explain things: http://dhmholley.co.uk/incrementals.html